# Why is Firestore storing the number as a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this form where I'll submit it in firestore. I wanted to save the `counter` as a number and not as a string in Firestore. I've already declared the type as a "number" and it still saves as a string.

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc();
      const ref = userRef.set({
        ....,
        counter
      });
      console.log(" saved");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
   <Grid item>
            <TextField
              type="number"
              label="counter"
              fullWidth
              required
              value={counter}
              onChange={(e) => setCounter(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Grid>
```

Comment: @Dai this -  `const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inputs are always string types.

You can convert to number when updating state each input change:

```
onChange={(e) => setCounter(Number(e.target.value))}
```

(and as @Dai pointed out `valueAsNumber` - [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement))

> **valueAsNumber**
>
> double: Returns the value of the element, interpreted as one of the
> following, in order:
>
> - A time value
> - A number
> - NaN if conversion is impossible

```
onChange={(e) => setCounter(e.target.valueAsNumber)}
```

Or convert to number when updating the store:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc();
    const ref = userRef.set({
      ....,
      counter: Number(counter),
    });
    console.log(" saved");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: "Inputs are always string types." - yes, buuuuut while `HTMLInputElement.value` is always a `string`,  there is also `valueAsNumber` and `valueAsDate` (depending on your `<input type=""` />` of course.

Comment: Note that `valueAsNumber` will be `NaN` _unless_ the input has `<input type="number" />`.